# P5js program shows up black on Ipad

Tags: javascript, p5.js

So I was making a game with the p5js library and another one which is mostly unknown but which I am sure is not problem. Code as simple as this:

```
var button;
var player;
var x = 0, y = 0.5, z = 0

function setup() {
    createCanvas3D(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    background3D("#ffffff");
    changeCamera(ORTHOGRAPHIC);
    hideToolbox();
    console.log(width, height)
    hideGrid()

    noStroke();
    fill(255);
    ellipseMode(RADIUS);

    diffuse("orange");
    roughness(0.1);

    player = sphere(x, y, z, 0.5);
    var name = prompt()
    player.name = name
    console.log(player)
}

function draw() {
    setCamera(10 + player.position.x, 10 + player.position.y, 10 + player.position.z, player.position.x, player.position.y, player.position.z)
}

function windowResized() {
    resizeCanvas3D(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}
```

will run fine on the pc and android. This means that the ball is showing up orange. However on an original IOS device like Ipad everything is showing up black. I also checked with the chrome console log and there seem to be no error.

If anybody knows how to fix it thank you because it is really bothering me and I have to have this project finished by sunday.